# jQuery onclick not working in browser Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, onclick, microsoft-edge

View:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceHolder">
        <button id="cmdMyButton">ButtonName</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
        $('body').on('click', "#cmdMyButton", function (e) {
            alert("alertmessage");
        });

        ...
```

Clicking the button cmdMyButton works in Firefox and Chrome, but does absolutely nothing in Edge. I do not get the alert in Edge.

I have tried everything in this topic [Microsoft Edge: onclick event stops working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525721/microsoft-edge-onclick-event-stops-working)
But nothing worked for me. I am using jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: your button is missing in the html

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: Your code works fine in edge: https://jsfiddle.net/m9t49kys/ must be some other errors in your console

Comment: check your console for other error, could be that it breaks somewhere before the initialization

Comment: ERROR 1: SCRIPT5: SCRIPT5: Access denied. jquery.min.js (3,28933)

ERROR 2 : CONSOLE1810304: console.memory has not been implemented and returns 0 for all attributes. Use memory profiler to watch memory usage.

ERROR 3: CSS3119: No fonts available for @font-face-rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by updating jQuery to 3.3.1

**Header.asax:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/3.3.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: So what was the issue? In the question you posted that you were already using that version.

Comment: I had installed it. But I was refencing the older version in Header.asax, which was 1.3-something